# Dynamically-resizing a matrix causes segmentation fault

Tags: c

I would like to increase the height of a matrix encoded as a double-pointer, but every time I try, my code segfaults. I tried this but it does not work:

```
void get_matrix_bigger(int ** matrix, int height, int width)
{
   int new_width, new_height, i;
   scanf("%d%d", &new_height, &new_width);

   matrix = realloc(matrix, new_height * sizeof(int *));
   for(i = height; i < new_height; i++)
       matrix[i] = malloc(new_width * sizeof(int));

}

int main(void)
{
   int ** matrix, height, width;
   scanf("%d%d", &height, &width);

   matrix = malloc(height * sizeof(int *));

   for(i = 0; i < height; i++)
       matrix[i] = malloc(width * sizeof(int));

   get_matrix_bigger(matrix, height, width);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check if `realloc` succeeds. It returns null upon failure.

Comment: It succeeds every time

Comment: If it succeeds, then something else is wrong. You do not show enough of your code that we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In get_matrix_bigger function you should pass ***matrix, otherwise after you get out from get_matrix_bigger you still got old pointer on stack.

```
void get_matrix_bigger(int *** matrix, int height, int width)
{
   int new_width, new_height, i;
   scanf("%d%d", &new_height, &new_width);

   *matrix = realloc(*matrix, new_height * sizeof(int *));
   for(i = height; i < new_height; i++)
       *matrix[i] = malloc(new_width * sizeof(int));

}
```

And use it in main as:

```
get_matrix_bigger(&matrix, height, width);
```

Comment: i got it finally .. i think in that for is (*matrix)[i] instead of without ()